# Loading large DAE file in SceneKit fails on real iPhone

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am unable to launch my scenekit game in my iphone . When i run in real device iphone i got this error
__79-[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder initWithRenderCommandEncoder:parent:descriptor:]_block_invoke:738: failed assertion `Exceeded HW limit of resources used by render encoder working in Memoryless mode.'
Chat Conversation End
i am adding some piece of code here

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Update2/Tunnel-005.dae" )!




    rail  = (scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ID78487", recursively: true))!

    rail.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.static()

    rail.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 1

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(rail)
```

Any help??

Comment: As a guess, sounds like you're loading something that won't fit into the available memory. Can we see the code that triggers the error?

Comment: @HalMueller i load a collada .dae file of 90 mb and there are 50 planes in the scene .When i see run code and see memory debuger it takes 650 mb and 100% cpu why all this.As i just load only 90 mb collada file...

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

A 90 MB DAE file is fairly large, and the error message does suggest you're running out of some resource. How about using the Scene Editor and converting it to SCN format?